# Question ban :(

Tags: support

Okay I got one really bad question which I can't delete because it has an answer and keep getting downvotes :(

I do not think it's a bad question. The man simply doesn't tell. It may be more appropriate for linux forum rather than server fault.

Also this is a question and answer site. I got one question merged. Yea IOtop is already explained in the previous question but it doesn't tell anything.

What should I do?

Is this because I asked too many questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact heuristics behind question bans are not known outside of SE. Looking at your profile, you have 3 deleted questions, 4 closed questions and sundry downvotes which is somewhat more negative then you state above.

If you are getting the message:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account

Then [you need to see this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) for detailed information on why you're banned and what you can do about it.

In short:

- There is an automatic filter that will ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of extremely poor posts.
- The details of the filter are secret, but it is partly based on downvotes.  If your questions and/or answers are getting many downvotes, you are likely to be banned.
- Deleted questions and deleted answers count towards the automatic ban.  If a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they were not suitable for the site.
- In order to get un-banned, you need to edit some of your existing questions and/or answers to improve them.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that moderators can't affect *automatic* bans. Which means we can't tell when someone is banned, nor can we unban if we desire. The only way out is to edit your stuff to get on the other side of the ban threshold.

Comment: I am not sure what the ban is for, but most likely asking too many questions lead to it. I mean I improve my points from 1 to 64. I even answered some questions, the ban is still there. Looks like one downvote on that one question is the tipping point.

Comment: @SharenEayrs No, it's not one downvote on one question... It's the overall low quality of your questions, as shown by their lack of upvotes and the fact that some are deleted.

Comment: It's stupid. How are you supposed to get out of a question ban without asking better questions? Also, if most of your questions are deleted, how are you supposed to improve them?!?!?!?!?!? Stupid!

Answer (score 5):

[Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) is for Professional System Administrators (et al) only. You appear to be not a system administrator, and not doing administration is a professional capacity. Your questions involve very basic concepts that would be much more approriate on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com). See our [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq), and the FAQs from those other sites, for more details.

Question Bans are not due to one single question, and deleting the Question does not remove it from consideration toward the ban. You must improve your existing Question or Answer quality if you want to ask new Questions. [For more details see this Post with tons of details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Comment: I am aware of it. Some questions are downvoted for being too easy. Also the downvotes have no comment whatsoever. Moroever, being too easy is not listed anywhere as being off topic. Oh well.... Good bye I guess :)

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to misunderstand what [SF]'s purpose. This is supposed to be a community of professionals, who can give and take a bit of knowledge. You have contributed almost nothing but poor questions. To protect the contributing community members from people like you, the automatic ban was implemented. If you have no desire to become a contributing member of the community, then please do leave. The other members have no desire to constantly be burdened by someone who never feels the responsibility (or capacity) to give back.

Comment: `@ChrisS:` I disagree your point here. Cause we are learner and never be equipped 100% so we may ask sometimes silly question which might look like off topic or bad questions but learning never stops. `If you are feeling proud to say some one to leave` then you might think twice before saying it cause one bad word cause consequences which no one has seen yet. I am not offering violence but its about being normal and calm with the user and their effort. I know you can not learn everything for free but if you do not put effort I am sure definitely you can not learn anything.

Comment: @PratapSingh [SF] is not for users; it is for Professional System Administrators only. People who are unable to contribute to the community are here for the wrong reasons. Threatening violence is way over the line - I have chosen my words carefully, perhaps you should do the same.

Comment: `@ChrisS`: I did choose mine too carefully ..

Comment: @PratapSingh the community has no problem with new sysadmins or ones who are experienced in one area, but who have to step outside of their comfort zone and need help. But we do expect certain standards of professionalism. There's a big difference between asking for help when you run into a problem and expecting people to tell you how to do your job for you. And we don't like the latter. There's a strong culture of 'teach a person to fish' inherent in systems administrators.